# Admin profile locked on Android 4.4 KitKat tablet

Tags: factory-reset, tablet, password

My daughter has locked my admin profile on my our tablet and there's only her user profile open but I can't reset from there. tried the volume up button and power on to reset my tablet but nothing seems to work is there another way? Please help

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming she either set a new pin/password for you by mistake or you already had a pin/password before she locked it that you cannot remember. Either way you need to reset the pic/password. Here are the instructions for Android 4.4 which you are using:

"Older versions of Android — Android 4.4 KitKat and older — have an integrated way to bypass your pattern, PIN, or other password if you forget it."

"To find this feature, first enter an incorrect pattern or PIN five times at the lock screen. You’ll see a “Forgot pattern,” “forgot PIN,” or “forgot password” button appear. Tap it. You’ll be prompted to enter the username and password of the Google account associated with your Android device."

http://www.howtogeek.com/226942/what-to-do-if-you-forget-your-android-phone%E2%80%99s-pin-pattern-or-password/

If you cannot remember the password to your Google account then complete this process first:
https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery/

If you have still access to the number you used when creating the Google account, recovery will be easy, otherwise you will need to answer some security questions first.

Once you recover your account you can go back to the pin/password reset instructions for your tablet above.

Comment: Some models had modified their Android images to remove that little feature even on 4.4 :D :D :D . Thank you, Alcatel Pop C9. Absolutely no way provided to recover from a forgotten credential on that one. Only way (without finding an exploit) is to build an automatic input machine and let it try all the 10^6 (or 10^7; I can't remember) possibilities :D.

Answer (score 0):

Nah, just make sure when she opens it backup and recovery is on and then do a hard reset
If not download mobizon screen recorder and then in about phone enable developers options and enable see screen tap so you could see the pass word easily
If its samsung sign in your account in find my phone Samsung and unlock ur device